# Javascript click listener, but doesn't trigger on child element?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to move over to using plain old Javascript (moving away from jQuery, due to speed issues). I need to trigger a click event on something, and then toggle a class on the main element. Here is what I have:

```
document.querySelector('.wrapper-dropdown').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   event.target.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h12o073L/17/

The problem I've got, is that I ONLY want the main element to add the class - not the child! Currently if I click on one of the prices, that gets the **.active** class (whereas I want the `.wrapper-dropdown` element to have the class added)

I've got to admit - I've become very lazy with jQuery, so I'm probably missing something simple ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) function to select the targeted `.wrapper-dropdown`.

> The `Element.closest()` method returns the closest ancestor of the
>   current element *(or the current element itself)* which matches the
>   selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it
>   returns `null`.

```
document.querySelector('.wrapper-dropdown').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   event.target.closest('.wrapper-dropdown').classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```js
document.querySelector('.wrapper-dropdown').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.target.closest('.wrapper-dropdown').classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```html
<div id="dd-price-from" class="wrapper-dropdown" tabindex="1">
  <span>Price From</span>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li data-what="20"><a href="#">€20</a></li>
    <li data-what="50"><a href="#">€50</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `.active` class to only be added to the `.wrapper-dropdown` You can use the `currentTarget` this will always refers to the element where you attach the event handler.

```
document.querySelector('.wrapper-dropdown').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   event.currentTarget.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` inside event listener function:

```
document.querySelector('.wrapper-dropdown').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 this.classList.toggle("active");
```

});